# logstash parsing newlines between json fields

Tags: json, logstash, event-log, elk

I've got json files after converting windows eventlogs using powershell's get-winevent. I want to upload it to ELK using logstash input file method. But the problem is that JSON fields are separated by a comma and newline ( ,\n ) (I assume so). This is making one line of json to get populated in 1st log in elasticsearch, next json line in 2nd log, whereas the entire one log was supposed to be in one row in elastic. Also, this json is nested and has dictionaries with list. I cannot find any resource that talks about it. Wonder how come this has not been asked yet anywhere. Below is the log-

```
    "MachineName":  "DESKTOP-E46TUNE",
    "UserId":  null,
    "TimeCreated":  "\/Date(1625113095126)\/",
    "MatchedQueryIds":  [

                        ],
    "Bookmark":  {

                 },
    "TaskDisplayName":  "User Account Management",
    "KeywordsDisplayNames":  [
                                 "Audit Success"
                             ],
    "Properties":  [
                       {
                           "Value":  "\r\n\t\t%%2080\r\n\t\t%%2082\r\n\t\t%%2084"
                       },
                       {
                           "Value":  "%%1793"
                       },
                       {
                           "Value":  "-"
                       }
                   ],
    "Message":  "A user account was created.\r\n\r\nSubject:\r\n\tSecurity ID:\t\tS-1-5-21-2249204231-554948959-1540642952-1001\r\n\tAccount Name:\t\tkriss\r\n\tAccount Domain:\t\tDESKTOP-E46TUNE\r\n\tLogon ID:\t\t0x103E5E\r\n\r\nNew Account:\r\n\tSecurity ID:\t\tS-1-5-21-2249204231-554948959-1540642952-1002\r\n\tAccount Name:\t\tnaveen1\r\n\tAccount Domain:\t\tDESKTOP-E46TUNE\r\n\r\nAttributes:\r\n\tSAM Account Name:\tnaveen1\r\n\tDisplay Name:\t\t\u003cvalue not set\u003e\r\n\tUser Principal Name:\t-\r\n\tHome Directory:\t\t\u003cvalue not set\u003e\r\n\tHome Drive:\t\t\u003cvalue not set\u003e\r\n\tScript Path:\t\t\u003cvalue not set\u003e\r\n\tProfile Path:\t\t\u003cvalue not set\u003e\r\n\tUser Workstations:\t\u003cvalue not set\u003e\r\n\tPassword Last Set:\t\u003cnever\u003e\r\n\tAccount Expires:\t\t\u003cnever\u003e\r\n\tPrimary Group ID:\t513\r\n\tAllowed To Delegate To:\t-\r\n\tOld UAC Value:\t\t0x0\r\n\tNew UAC Value:\t\t0x15\r\n\tUser Account Control:\t\r\n\t\tAccount Disabled\r\n\t\t\u0027Password Not Required\u0027 - Enabled\r\n\t\t\u0027Normal Account\u0027 - Enabled\r\n\tUser Parameters:\t\u003cvalue not set\u003e\r\n\tSID History:\t\t-\r\n\tLogon Hours:\t\tAll\r\n\r\nAdditional Information:\r\n\tPrivileges\t\t-"
}
```

I have removed 70% of the repeated data and trimmed the log to 30% of its original size for ease of understanding. Can someone plz suggest how to address each field? 
Also would be great if you could point me to some good resources for reference. 
Thanks in advance

EDIT: The logline above is the only content for single eventlog for user creation ( user_creation-log.json ). The logstash config file-

```
input {
    file {
    path => "/home/kriss/triage/user_creation-log.json"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
}    }
filter { json { source => "message"} }
output {
    elasticsearch { hosts=>"localhost" index=>"eventlog" }
    stdout { }
}
```

Comment: not sure if you have already looked at `json filter plugin` but here is the link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html.  take a look at it and ask precisely what is your input and what you want to see as output. Also if your Elasticsearch has mappings for nested objects, there should be no issues sending a nested object from logstash to Elasticsearch unless you post a specific problem (with what you have and what you want to see)

Comment: If you want to ingest windows event logs in elasticsearch why not try Winlogbeat that will collect the events and do the parsing? Any reason to not use it?

Comment: I collect event logs from systems and use them for analysis of incidents. The purpose is doing dead forensics.

Comment: @JBone, I saw the official elastic documentation, but it nowhere talks about complicated logs. But here the logs are having newlines and are nested.
I am adding the config file also to post.

Comment: I see something related to parsing the multilines, but not sure how to use it here. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/multiline.html#:~:text=The%20multiline%20codec%20is%20the%20preferred%20tool%20for,use%20the%20multiline%20codec%20to%20handle%20multiline%20events.

Comment: @nav33n Since you are working with Windows Event logs in this case, I would recommend that you take a look at [Winlogbeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/winlogbeat/current/_winlogbeat_overview.html), It can read event logs directly from Windows systems or reading `.evtx` file, it would save you a lot of work as the events would be already be parsing, no need to try to fix your json to parse it.